# Best way to export NEF files to JPG for best Facebook quality in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, export, image-quality, image-format

Hey I'm looking for compression and exporting recommendations!

Unfortunately, I took an awesome picture of a drone in flight while my Nikon was set to save NEF / RAW files.... So I have this great shot I've edited in Gimp and it appears crystal clear until I upload it to Facebook.

I've tried setting it to Facebook's sizing recommendations (720px, 960px or 2048px wide) as well as comprising the file size to under 100KB. I export it to JPG for cmy personal color preferences. The picture looks great on my computer still, and then I upload it to an HD folder on Facebook and it's disgusting...

Anyone know the exact parameters I should use in GIMP or what I should set each individual compression option to when exporting? Any advice is appreciated!!! I want this photo to sparkle online a little more than what I've been able to achieve so far. Thanks!

Comment: Questions: 1) Is the 960 px JPG still fine when at first closed and then reopened 2) Have you any idea of the colorspace (sRGB, Adobe RGB, Nikons own, no color management) that your JPG was stamped to have?

Comment: Normally you should use a RAW-processing app (there are several good open-source ones, RawTherapeen, Nufraw, Photozone, Darktable, Digikam...). Some of these can also work as Gimp plugins. No experience with NEF files but I read that with some alien filetypes (no plugin for them), Gimp actually opens the embedded JPEG thumbnail, which is much smaller than the actual image. Also, download the file from FB and check that it is the same as the one you uploaded, FB often recompresses images.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact problem when you upload to Facebook - what do you consider "disgusting"?  That's not really very descriptive.

Facebook processes all uploaded images and adds more compression, and turns all images into JPEGs whatever format you upload - so not much you can probably do there. If the colours are off, make sure you export the image with an sRGB colour profile.

Facebook is well known for mangling images. If you want to share images with better quality, there are better image sharing websites out there. Even free sites like Flickr are far superior.

Answer (score 0):

Natively Gimp doesn't support the NEF format, you need plugins, such as the ancient UFRaw or the more recent Photoflow. But there are plenty of other free apps that will make a JPEG from your NEF: Nikon Capture; RawTherapee, DarkTable...